# How to create an object upon confirmation of deletion in DeleteView in Django

Tags: django

In Django 3, I want to delete an object and upon the user confirming the deletion, create an unrelated object. The code I wrote below creates the unrelated object as soon as the user clicks "delete", but before the user has confirmed the deletion. I want the unrelated object to be created upon confirmation of deletion.

```
class PromoteQuestionToMeta(DeleteView):
    model = QuestionList
    fields = []

    template_name = 'search/questionlist_confirm_delete.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        questionlist_object = self.object
        MetaQuestionList.objects.create(question=questionlist_object.question, created_by=questionlist_object.created_by)

        return context

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('home:home')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the [**`.delete(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.DeletionMixin.delete) and create an object:

```
class PromoteQuestionToMeta(DeleteView):
    model = QuestionList
    fields = []
    template_name = 'search/questionlist_confirm_delete.html'

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        result = super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
        MetaQuestionList.objects.create(
            question=self.object.question,
            created_by=self.object.created_by
        )
        return result

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('home:home')
```